# Antonyme de raréfier

Tags: vocabulaire, verbes, antonyme

Pour dire que quelque chose, qu'un événement se raréfie, je peux utiliser le verbe raréfier.
Par exemple,

> les problèmes de distribution se raréfient.

Mais comment dire le contraire, que quelque chose est de plus en plus fréquent ? Je n'ai pas trouver de verbe pour exprimer cette idée.

Dans mon dictionnaire il y a condenser comme antonyme de raréfier, mais cela ne me semble pas le plus adéquat.
Exemple de phrase que je voudrais écrire :

> L'utilisation du système de connexion xxx va se **condenser** dans les
>   prochains mois.

Quel verbe serait le plus adapté ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Multiplier](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/multiplier)

> les problèmes de distribution se multiplient.

[Intensifier](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/intensifier)

> L'utilisation du système de connexion xxx va s'intensifier dans les prochains mois.

Aussi: [s'étendre](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9tendre), [s'amplifier](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/amplifier), [s'accroître](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/accroitre)…

Comment: Merci, cela compensera un peu mes lacunes en vocabulaire.